# modal logic proof question

Tags: modal-logic

If we have $$ \vdash A \rightarrow B $$then we can derive $$ \vdash \Box A \rightarrow \Box B $$ By necessity

But we should then also be able to derive $$ \vdash \diamond A \rightarrow \diamond B $$

Intuitivly, it makes sense, but I am not sure how to prove it. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) $\vdash A \to B$

2) $\vdash \lnot B \to \lnot A$

3) $\vdash \Box \lnot B \to \Box \lnot A$

4) $\vdash \lnot \Box \lnot A \to \lnot \Box \lnot B$.

Comment: I knew I had to use the duality property, but never thought of rewriting the implication, thanks!